# Saving the script as a project with Document.saveAs in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to save the script as a project to work with it later on

```
var doc = app.documents.add(null, 1080 , 1080, 1);
var file = New File("/c/Users/user/Documents/05illustratorScript.ai");
app.activeDocument.saveAs(file);
```

It marks line2 (`expected ;`)

If I do instead

```
var doc = app.documents.add(null, 1080 , 1080, 1);
app.activeDocument.saveAs("/c/Users/user/Documents/05illustratorScript.ai");
```

It says Illegal argument - argument 1 (on the line2)

Has anyone successfully used this method?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I was missing to include the second argument of the method `Document.saveAs` which is the "Save Options" , they are in turn another object that needs to be created.

The way to create a new document and save it as a certain `.ai` is

```
var doc = app.documents.add(null, 1080 , 1080, 1);
var newFile = new File("/c/your/Path/file.ai");
var saveOptions = new IllustratorSaveOptions();
app.activeDocument.saveAs(newFile , saveOptions);
```